# Azure API Management - Cannot test within API Management, but endpoint works in browser

Tags: azure-api-management

I am using Azure API Management to host an API that I coded.  I am unable to use the test tab for individual operations.  However, I can copy the request url from the test tab for the operation and results are displayed correctly.  Below is the error message displayed when trying the functionality from the AMS - specifically, pressing the send button.
[image: Error]

I tried looking in the logs, specifically to display the last 100 failed requests... But no results are returned.

I haven't setup products or subscriptions yet. I have a third party company testing the API at the moment, so I have to be careful I don't disrupt their testing whilst I wait for another slot to be setup. Can I add allow tracing to the 'Built-in all-access subscription' without any disruption?
[image]

Comment: Can you please check the `Trace`?

Comment: I haven't setup products or subscriptions yet.  I have a third party company testing the API at the moment, so I have to be careful I don't disrupt their testing whilst I wait for another slot to be setup.  Can I add allow tracing to the 'Built-in all-access subscription' without any disruption?  I have added this text along with a screenshot into main question.

Comment: I tried the trace button instead of send.  We are using IP whitelisting to manage access.  The call is coming from an IP address that is not the one listed as the Virtual IP in the AMS overview blade.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer - post your comment as an answer please, so I can give you points.  I have just added the IP address shown in the trace to the white list and it is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the `Trace` for more details regarding the `403` response.